# How to get fwrite() not to double quotes?

Tags: r, data.table

I read a csv file containing html code in its fields using `fread`, do some maintenance on it and write the resulting datatable to a file using `fwrite`. Problem is that now all the html is filled with quadruple quotes such as `colspan="""""7""""`. There is the `qmethod` argument but I'm not sure how to use it as I'm not interested to escape quotes with backslash either.

Is it possible to avoid that or do I have to use sed ?

For instance I got the csv file :

```
htmlcode,id
<colspan="7">,1
<colspan="8">,2
```

I read that into a datatable with `fread`, I remove the id column and write the datatable back into a csv file with `fwrite` I get:

```
htmlcode
<colspan=""""7"""">
<colspan=""""8"""">
```

Comment: i actually didn't get your question all, but would using `gsub` to replace mutiple occurence of `"` with a single `"` work?

Comment: FWIW base64 encoding HTML "fields" is usually a much better idea than storing in raw form unless we're talking database "blobs" or WARC files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possible solutions (using **v1.10.0** of **data.table**):

**1:** Use the `quote = FALSE` parameter:

```
fwrite(dt, 'fwrite.csv', quote = FALSE)
```

When opening the file in a text editor, you will see this:

```
htmlcode
<colspan="7">
<colspan="8">
```

**2:** Replace the double brackets with single one (as also suggeted by @joel.wilson in the comments):

```
dt[, htmlcode := gsub('\"', '\'', htmlcode)]
fwrite(dt, 'fwrite.csv')
```

When opening the file in a text editor, you will see this:

```
htmlcode
<colspan='7'>
<colspan='8'>
```

Comment: actually quote=FALSE still doubles the quotes ie `""7""` instead of `"7"`

Comment: @ChiseledAbs on my PC it doesn't (macOS); which version of `data.table` are you using?

Comment: 1.10.0 on linux, maybe it's due to the fact that the whole field is braced in quotes eg `"<colspan="8">"`. Would you know how to fix that or do I have to make substitutions ?

Comment: @ChiseledAbs The only other option I can come up with now is setting the `qmethod`-parameter to either `escape` or `double` and see what that does.